# C# Async window showing after all code was running

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I am trying to implement a "Loading Window" into my WPF-Application which should be shown when the client wants to send a message to the server and then should be closed after the responce was received. As I use async methods, this should not be a big problem, but somehow the window shows **after** the response was received and closes instantly (as expected).

Here are some code snippets

```
    public async Task<CommunicationMessage> SendAndReadMessageSync(string message, bool showLoadingScreen = true) {

        // Show loading screen if needed
        if (showLoadingScreen == true) {
            await Globals.MessageController.ShowLoadingScreen(); // This method is the second one
        }

        // Send a message to the server
        SendMessageSync(message);

        // Receive the response from the server
        CommunicationMessage response = ReadMessageSync();

        // Close loading screen
        if (showLoadingScreen == true) {
            await Globals.MessageController.CloseLoadingScreen();
        }

        // return the response
        return response;
    }


    public async Task ShowLoadingScreen(string title = "Lade Daten", string message = "Einen Moment Geduld bitte") {

        await Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(async delegate {

            // Create the loading screen
            LoadingScreen ls = new LoadingScreen(title, message) {
                IsModal = true
            };

            // Store the screen inside list
            loadingScreens.Add(ls);

            // Show the screen
            await this.ShowChildWindowAsync(ls, ChildWindowManager.OverlayFillBehavior.FullWindow);
        }));
    }
```

My thinkings of the executions are that the loading screen will show up independently of the **SendMessageSync()**-Method which could last for 10 seconds. After the client gets the response the loading screen will be closed.

Am I doing something wrong or did I forget something? If you need some more code please let me know

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to encapsulate the sending of the message in a Task. Right now it will run on the UI thread. So it looks like the UI thread is bussy and simply cannot show your waiting window.

Comment: This was the answer! Thank you alot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dispatcher.Invoke instead of Dispatcher.BeginInvoke in this scenario. The Dispatcher.Invoke will show the window immediately in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately it won't, it still shows up after all data was received